# CouchDB validation prevents DELETE

Tags: javascript, validation, couchdb

Wrote validation func for couch:

```
function(newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx) { 
function isNullOrWhiteSpace(str){ return str === null || str.match(/^\s*$/) !== null; }
function require(field, message) {
    message = message || "Document must have a " + field;
    if ((!newDoc[field]) || isNullOrWhiteSpace(newDoc[field])) throw({forbidden : message});
  };
 require("title");
 require("content"); 
}
```

All good, except that I can't delete documents now — validation doesn't allow me to do it, saying that document must contain `title` and `id`.

How to detect which operation is going now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is really couch-like:

```
function(newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx) { 
function isNullOrWhiteSpace(str){ return str === null || str.match(/^\s*$/) !== null; }
function require(field, message) {
    message = message || "Document must have a " + field;
    if ((!newDoc[field]) || isNullOrWhiteSpace(newDoc[field])) throw({forbidden : message});
  };

if(!newDoc._deleted){
 require("title");
 require("content"); 
}
}
```

Key point is checking new doc for `_deleted` field. If it exists, document on the way to deletion. That's interesting, but strange — so, for update checking I must handle revision changing? But in main way, it works.